# Retrieve data by specific value in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am new to firebase. I am making an app in vue and firebase. Here is I have ref 'users' like this snap.

[image]

In text:

`-L0PZ870WKlPC2BpRxbw
     email: "rebowit@gmail.com"
     name: "Carol Howard"
 -L0P_xMlFVxOFuQ0yHne
     email: "dekyl@hotmail.com"
     name: "Alvin Boyd"`

I want to get `name` where `email` I will provide. Need solution in JavaScript which needs to able run in vue app. A function like this would be appriciate

`function(email){ 
   // some code
   return name
}`

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here bellow if you have a user email, then you can retrieve user name as follow;

```
getNameByEmail(email) {
        var db = firebase.database();
        var ref = db.ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email);
        ref.once('value', snapshot => {
           if (snapshot.exists()) {
               var name = snapshot.val();
               name = Object.values(name);
               name = name[0].name;
               console.log('User email : ' + email + ' User name: '+ name );
           } else {
              console.log('There is no user who has email like '+ email)
           }
    })

}
```

In case, if you are searching often users with emails, then better to define index for better performance set databse rules like;

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": { ".indexOn": ["email"] }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, your solution returns `undefined` for the name. But when I change `snapshot.val().name` to `snapshot.val()` it returns object like this: https://ibb.co/idYepm

Comment: Seams you have the data. this is asynchronous function retrieving data takes time. So consider where you console the data.

Comment: Though its returning object with key so I have solved that problem by doing this `name = snapshot.val()
              name = Object.values(name)
              name = name[0].name`